# Is the recall of Solimo coffee capsules a serious issue?

Tags: coffee-machines, capsule

We have a Nescafe Dolce Gusto coffee machine and we usually buy Solimo branded capsules to it.
This week I got an email from the shop, saying:

> Solimo Dolce Gusto* compatible Cafè Au Lait pods- UTZ certified- 96
>   pods (6 x 16)
>
> The product you purchased is affected because it may contain plastic
>   fragments from the pod. If you still have this product, please throw
>   it away immediately and do not use it. There is no need for you to
>   return any product to us.

I contacted customer service, but they weren't really aware of this issue but tried to convince me this is not serious.

I tried to search for an incident report or any news why this was called back and how many products were affected, but couldn't find anything.

Do you know how did they find out this product defect and what are the health risks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick search and didn't find anything either.  If it was very serious there would articles about it all over the place. It would be a natural clickbait for the newspapers. "Coffee Recall - Read All About It"

If it is as described then it sounds benign from a health perspective and the notice is the company covering itself from legal action.